# how to make web application highly available between AZ's ? I am confused about route 53 and ELB layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

How should we configure Route53 and ELB between 2 AZ's?

route53 pointing to two ELB on each AZ and ELB distributing traffic to ec2 (web tier)?

please share your environment detail about how its accomplished and what challenges did you face in terms of performance / Availibilit/ security

thanks

Comment: Take a look at the AWS Reference Architectures: https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ELB exists across AZs. A single ELB actually creates an instance of itself in each AZ. You don't need to do anything with Route53 to achieve HA across AZs if you are using an ELB.

Comment: exactly @Launchpad Mcquack -- Route53 just needs an A or CNAME record to Elastic Beanstalk hostname (route53 alias or cname record). Elastic Beanstalk will balance traffic across two or more AZs ensuring that if AZ A goes down your application will still serve requests from AZ B. It is very resilient -- availability has not been an issue for me. Performance and security really come down to your application. AWS is fully capable of serving a secure and performant application but your application code / instance size selection can impair either of those requirements.

Comment: Thanks Dave and Mark for your response.